# Where can I get the LIB file import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

Tags: java

I have the following line of code

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
```

which is giving me a

```
javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved
```

where can I find the library file for this import?

Comment: What LIB file? Java uses JAR files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module **javax.xml.bind** has been renamed and is also deprecated as of **Java 9**.

To workaround you can add `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to `javac` compilation. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/9428319)

Or switch back to **Java 8** or older

Answer (score 2):

If you have a maven build, add the following to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```